# Configure email for AWS lightsail cpanel and Godaddy registered domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cpanel, amazon-lightsail

I have recently moved to AWS lightsail using cpanel from godaddy hosting. I was able to point my domain to the hosting and the website is all working good.

I am trying to create email from cpanel hosted on AWS lightsail, but i am not able to get emails.

The domain is hosted on Godaddy platform, i tried various combination of A,MX records but i am unable to start my email account or get connected to the emails to receive or send emails.

Is there anything that i can refer to for adding the DNS records and if there any changes to be done on AWS to get this started would be really helpful. I have searched through almost all articles and finally came down here to see solution.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, AWS blocks outbound traffic on port 25 on all Lightsail
> instances. To send outbound traffic on port 25, you must request that
> this restriction be removed.

Once logged into the AWS console, you can request to remove the email sending limitations using this form: https://support.console.aws.amazon.com/support/contacts#/rdns-limits

You can read a full article [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lightsail-port-25-throttle) with instructions.